# upload form only works in Firefox when uploading ASCII .stl 3D files

Tags: php, forms, post, mime-types

**uploadform.html** and **upload_file.php** (below) works fine in Firefox but fails in Chrome, IE, and Safari when uploading ASCII .stl 3D files. Error message is "Invalid file" and problem occurs with multiple computers and multiple .stl files. When I modify the code to support other file types like JPG and PDF it allows those file types in all four web browsers. Also, Firefox only allows the .stl upload if I include application/octet-stream in the mime types section. Why doesn't this work outside of Firefox?

**uploadform.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**upload_file.php:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
$allowedExts = array("stl");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if (
        (
   ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/sla")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/octet-stream")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/plain")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/unknown")
        )
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)
    )
{
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
            {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
            }
  else
            {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] /1024) . " KB<br />";

        if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
            {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
            }
else
      {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo "successful upload";
      }
           }
}
else
        {
    echo "Invalid file";
        }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does $_FILES["file"]["type"] contain in Chrome/IE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:** add `application/netfabb` to the section of allowed mime types. This is the mime type most browsers assign to .stl files. Firefox is an exception and identifies .stl files as `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: In case anyone interested, in 2021 Chrome gave me back `application/vnd.ms-pki.stl` as type for an STL file downloaded from Thingiverse.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the encoding attribute for IE.

```
 <form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" encoding="multipart/form-data" >
```

Comment: That didn't fix the problem. @shapeshifter

Comment: If you echo $_FILES["file"]["type"]; What does it return.

Comment: it echos this: application/netfabb

Comment: **Solution:**
add application/netfabb to the section of allowed mime types.

Much thanks to @shapeshifter for pointing me in this direction.

Comment: Great!   By the sound of it application/octet-stream is the default for unknown content types.  From a security point of view allowing octet-stream would be the same as allowing just about anything!  See, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Properly_Configuring_Server_MIME_Types